# Use PHP's mail() to do a blind copy e-mail?

Tags: php, email

I read that

> All custom headers (like From, Cc, Bcc and Date) are supported

from [PHP mail() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), but how do I actually implement this in my code? i.e. I don't want any recipient to see the other e-mails... ever.

Something like:

```
<?php
$to = "someguy@somesite.com, another@abc.com, someother@def.com";
$subject = "test message";
$msg = "this is a test";
$headers = "Bcc"; // <-- this?

if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) 
    echo "message sent";
else 
    echo "uh oh";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the examples on the page.

Here's one...

```
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

So you just add comma separated email addresses after `Bcc:` in the header.

Here's one with a loop that will add addresses from the array `$recip` to BCC:

```
$headers.="Bcc: "; 
while($count < $count_recip){ 
    $headers.=$recip[$count].", "; 
    $count ++; 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to cross your fingers and hope that the MTAs strip the BCC header from the message.

Answer (score 0):

Add the address to the envelope (i.e. the list of recipients), but not the message (i.e. the headers).